# How to pass variables over functions in python 3

Tags: python

```
#Test
def test():
    test1 = input("Type something: ")
test()
print(test1)


    print(test1)
NameError: name 'test1' is not defined
```

> **'test1' is not defined**

This is bothering me. I'm learning python and trying to write a small game for practice, and it seems that variables that are declared in a function don't carry over. Is there a way to get by this? Am I not supposed to use test() to close the function? Or should I figure out and use a class instead? Or perhaps is it just a quirk of python? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to return test.

Comment: Learn about local/global scopes

Answer (score 1):

By default, all the names assigned inside a function definition are put in the local scope (the
namespace associated with the function call). If you need to assign a name that
lives at the top level of the module enclosing the function, you can do so by declaring
it in a global statement inside the function. If you need to assign a name
that lives in an enclosing `def`, as of Python 3.X you can do so by declaring it in a
`nonlocal` statement.

Read this: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

You need to **return the value and store the returned value** to print it.

```
def test():
    test1 = input("Type something: ")
    return test1
a = test()
print(a)
```

In general, functions should rely on **arguments** and **return values** instead of **globals**.

Answer (score 1):

```
def test():
    test1 = input("Type something: ")
```

These two lines define a function called `test`.  When `test` is called (`test()`), the line inside will be run.  The line inside assigns input to the variable `test1`.  But `test1` is scoped to the `test` function -- the name `test1` only exists inside the function, so once the function ends, the name disappears.

Functions are called to produce output (or side-effects, but in this case, output).  You do that by using the `return` keyword to end your function and return a variable.  In this case, you could do `return test1` inside your function (technically you could just to `return input(...)` directly too, and skip the creation of the variable entirely).

```
test()
```

This calls the function.  You can do this at any time after the function is defined; you don't need to do it to "close" the function.

If you modify your function to `return` a value, then you'll need to do something with the return value on this line.  Something like `result = test()`.  That assigns the `return` value of `test` to the `result` variable.

```
print(test1)
```

This isn't working because `test1` only exists inside the function namespace, and you are calling this line outside of the function namespace.  If you've made the changes I suggested above, you can do `print(result)` instead.